# Robolectric @Config path value for manifest

Tags: robolectric

I am trying to run robolectric unit test but I am getting error as AndroidManifest.xml not found on path. Can anyone give me an example path of @Config manifest value. Is it relative path or absolute one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using maven to run your tests you can set as follows:

```
@Config(manifest = "../app/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SomeTestCase { ... }
```

Please note that if you are using Android Studio/Intellij and want to run your tests within the IDE you will have to make a change in the Run configuration. 
In Run->Edit configuration->Defaults->JUnit->Working directory set the value $MODULE_DIR$ and Android Studio will set the relative path in all junits just like Maven.

This worked for me however if the annotation fails, you can also create a file called "org.robolectric.Config.properties" and place it on your classpath. 
The file should contain something like the following:
**"manifest: ./app/AndroidManifest.xml"**

More information can be found here: [Configuring Robolectric 2.0](http://robolectric.blogspot.mx/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html)
A simple configuration using maven can be found here: [Simple Robolectric](https://github.com/marsucsb/simple-robolectric)

Comment: Simple Robolectrie link is dead.

Comment: I get an error: **WARNING: No manifest file found at ./../app/AndroidManifest.xml**