# Robolectric ignores custom and test application class when running more than one test

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, robolectric

For an Android app, I have Robolectric unit-tests.  I run them from Eclipse.

I'm using the Robolectric feature of providing a replacement `Application` class for Robolectric to use.  This class, call it `TestApplication`, extends my application class, call it `MyApplication`, which extends the Android `Application` class.

I've found that, when I run individual test cases, Robolectric uses the substitute Application class as expected.  But, if I create a run configuration for all the tests in the project, Robolectric reverts to using the Android `Application` class.  It ignores both `TestApplication` and `MyApplication`.

What could be causing this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the cause of the problem was that Robolectric was not using my project's AndroidManifest.xml when Eclipse ran a "run configuration" for a package or an entire project, as opposed to a single test class.

A fix that works is to use Robolectric's configuration feature to provide the location of the manifest.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17593052/369722).

Both the `@Config` and properties file solutions worked for me.  I preferred the properties file because it applies to the entire project, whereas the annotation has to be on every test class.

The properties file should be named "org.robolectric.Config.properties" and you should put it on your classpath (I did this by placing the file in the test project's source folder).

Assuming you have a `TestMyProject` containing Robolectric tests for `MyProject`, the file should contain the following.  (The path below is relative to `TestMyProject`).

`manifest=../MyProject/AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem with robolectric where the suite of tests would fail but a single test would run fine. It turned out there was a timing issues while running the suite. Try adding a wait timer or a sleep and see if it works

Comment: If there is some other solution that you found, please post the answer to it. Thanks